# Dask script fails on large csv file on a localhost environment

Tags: dask

We are trying to use Dask to clean up some data as part of an ETL process.
The original file is over 3GB csv .
When we run the code on a subset (1GB) the code runs successfully (with a few `user warning` regarding our cleaning procedures such as:

```
ddf[id1] = ddf[id1].str.extract(´(\d+)´)

repeater  = re.compile(r´((\d)\2{5,}´)
mask_repeater = ddf[id1].str.contrains(repeater, regex=True)
ddf = ddf[~mask_repeater]
```

On the 3GB file the process nearly completes (there is only one task left - drop-duplicates-agg) and then restarts from the middle (that is what I can see from the bokeh status website). we also see the warning which is the same as when the script starts to run.

```
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't detect a suitable IP address for reaching '8.8.8.8', defaulting to '127.0.0.1'...
```

I´m running on a offline single  windows64bit workstation with 24 cores .

Any suggestions?

Comment: I could not find the [dask logs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/debugging.html#logs)

Comment: Can you provide information about which scheduler are you using and if you're doing any setup that isn't mentioned in your writeup above?

Comment: I´m using the default scheduler.  just:
 `import dask.dataframe as dd 
dd.read_csv(...)`.   
No special setup

Comment: We are currently managing to  run a work around and run the  `compute()` before the `drop_duplicates`

Comment: We are having similar problems with the `groupby` operation. We may just need to import the data into a database to run the aggregation.

Comment: *I´m using the default scheduler. just: import dask.dataframe as dd dd.read_csv(...). No special setup*

This is inconsistent with that statement that you are watching the bokeh website, and the error you're reporting about reaching `8.8.8.8`.  Perhaps you are starting a `Client()` ?

Comment: If so then I recommend passing `Client(silence_logs=False)`

Comment: I thought the error  `...IP address for reaching '8.8.8.8'...` is due to running in an offline environment.  Since I'm running on a standalone workstation - I normally don't start with `Client()` but rather directly with `dd.read_parquet` or `dd.read_csv` - is this preferred? BTW I do encounter strange behavior when running from an IDE (like `pycharm`) compared when running from a `jupyter notebook` (where the behavior is more expected.